# How do you do to create the ViewModel part of your MVVM designs?

Tags: design, design-patterns, uml, mvvm

Sometimes, when I plan to create a program using this architectural pattern, I've got a lot of difficulties when I'm in the View Model phase.

I'm using WAF Framework to develop this architectural pattern. I'm a still a newbie.

Before you start, do you create all the UML design or do you use another tool to help you? How do you handle the design of your ViewModels ?

Comment: Do you have difficulties with MVVM in general or just with the step where you have to create your ViewModels ? You may have to reformat your question to make it clearier.

Comment: Only in the view models..

Comment: What, specifically, are you having trouble with when it comes to view models? That information would help us answer your question better.

Comment: @OscarFimbres : Reworked your question to go straighter to the point about the view models.

Answer (score 4):

The ViewModel is an abstraction of the View.

That means you need to know first what you want to diplay to the user. At least you should have a detailled sketch of what the UI will look like (There are many tools intended to do this: [MS Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx), [Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/), etc.). Or even a dummy UI without logic plugged behind, created with your development tool.

Once you have your view, the ViewModel will be the place to hold every binded value, and what could be called display logic, mainly formatting. A View Model can be a representation of one Model, a group of Models of the same type, or an aggregation of different models.

A simple exemple of View Model is the editing screen with a drop down list. Let's have a concrete example with a User that can be linked to a division :

```
public class UserModel 
{ 
   public string Username { get; set; } 
   public string EmailAddress { get; set; } 
   public int DivisionId { get; set; } 
} 

public class DivisionModel 
{ 
   public int DivisionId { get; set; } 
   public string DivisionName { get; set; } 
}
```

It wouldn't make sense to plug an IEnumerable of divisions in UserModel, so we create a View Model to represent a displayable User, with all the data needed to have a working screen where I can select a Division for that User :

```
public class UserViewModel 
{ 
   public UserModel User { get; set; } 
   public IEnumerable<DivisionModel> Divisions {get; set;} 
}
```

And that's it. Depending on the language I'll be using, I'll just have to feed a drop down list with the `IEnumerable` of `DivisionModels` and make it show the Name member.

Comment: +1 Basically sketch out your View, then take all the data from your sketch and put it in your ViewModel. So if your View lets users edit User data, you'll want a `UserModel` in your ViewModel. If the View has a DropDown to select a `User` to edit, you'll want a list of Users for the DropDown, and something to track the `SelectedItem` (can be either an `int` for Index or `User` for user object). If you have a Save button, you'll want an `ICommand` for the Save functionality.